Why can't gradle find the dependency?
I'm not a regular Java programmer.
Here's my build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
}

group = 'com.amkhrjee'
version = '0.0.1'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(22)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.1.0'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

Here's the error I am getting:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.1.0.
     Required by:
         root project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html


Here's the dependency I am using: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-auth/23.1.0
I am unable to figure out what's wrong with my config.
P.S. I tried adding google() in the repositories - didn't help.

This often happens because this specific version of the Firebase library is not available in the default mavenCentral repository. Many Firebase libraries, especially recent ones, are published to Google’s own Maven repository (maven.google.com) instead of Maven Central. If you take a closer look at the maven link you posted above you will see the note that indicates this

Add the google repo
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } // Add the Google Maven repository
}

